# How do I destroy a bullet after a collision or after a certain amount of time LibGDX Box2d

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I have a sprite that is supposed to shoot bullets. To shoot bullets I have an if statement that checks if his shooting animation is play and if it is then it should create a bullet which is created like this:

```
BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
  bdef.position.set(isaac.ISAACX, isaac.ISAACY);
  bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
  b2Body = world.createBody(bdef);
  b2Body.setBullet(true);

  fdef = new FixtureDef();
  shape = new CircleShape();
  shape.setRadius(3 / icsGame.PPM);

  fdef.shape = shape;
  b2Body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData("bullet");
```

I figured out how to position where the bullets are created and how to space them out I just can't figure out how to destroy them.

```
if(currentStateShooting == State.NORTH && shootTimer >= SHOOT_WAIT_TIME){
  shootTimer = 0;
  defineBullet();
  b2Body.applyLinearImpulse(0, 3, b2Body.getWorldCenter().x, b2Body.getWorldCenter().y, true);
  if(wall.destroyed){
    System.out.println("hi");
    b2Body.destroyFixture(b2Body.createFixture(fdef));
    world.destroyBody(b2Body);
    wall.destroyed = false;
  }
}
```

currently that if statement takes in a boolean from the wall class:

```
public class wall extends interactiveTileObject {
  public static boolean destroyed = false;
  public wall(playScreen screen, Rectangle bounds) {
    super(screen, bounds);
    fixture.setUserData(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBodyHit() {
    destroyed = true;
  }
}
```

The problem is that it just won't destroy the body. Any idea why this is happening? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should  try using Actors for diplay your bullet.

And after that you will be able to use action on you actors.
Action let you easily define a lot of comportement easily and respecting libgdx lifecycle

In your case a RemoveAction.
[A link to the javadoc of Actions](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/actions/Actions.html)